# Cassandra PHP libcassandra.so.2: cannot open shared object file

Tags: php, cassandra, centos7

So I have spent the best part of the day trying (and failing) to get the php driver for apache cassandra to install on my server (CentOS 7).

After a lot of mucking about and a few grey hairs i have finally got the driver to install but unfortunately it doesnt actually load.

In my apache Error log i get
`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/cassandra.so' - libcassandra.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

I have checked and the libcassandra.so.2 file does indeed exist in /usr/local/lib64/libcassandra.

Has anyone come across a similar ptoblem?
Any help would be appreciated.

Im Running CentOS 7 and PHP 5.4.16 and Apache 2.4.6

Thanks
Matt.

Comment: aaaaand typically right after i asked the question i found the answer ¬¬. ill give it a proper test tomorrow and if it all works ill add the answer just in case anyone else has the same issue.

Answer (score 13):

the problem i was having was that libcassandra was installed into `/usr/local/lib64` not `/usr/lib64`

a simple `ln -s /usr/local/lib64/libcassandra.so.2 /usr/lib64/libcassandra.so.2` command fixed the problem

Comment: I remember once in the past I was facing with some other error like this. Anyway thank you man